# How to add sd card to android emulator in android studio 1.5.1?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard, android-virtual-device

I am using android studio 1.5.1 and ubuntu 14.04. I want to add sd card to mobile device emulator.

I created new virtual device using Android Virtual Device Manager from android studio menus Tools --> Android --> AVD Manager. But there is no option to add sd card to virtual device. So tried command line tool `mksdcard` to create sd card as per instructions given in [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/mksdcard.html).

```
./mksdcard -l mySdCard 128M mySdCardFile.img
```

And then used following command to start emulator and load sd card.

`./emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_23_x86 -sdcard mySdCardFile.img`

But it gave me warning emulator: `WARNING: Emulated hardware doesn't support SD Cards. -sdcard option ignored.`

How can I use sd card in emulator? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Go to your avd location (typically at `~/.android/avd/your-android-avd-id`)

There is a file named `config.ini`

Open that and look for the line `hw.sdCard=no` and change it to `hw.sdCard=yes`.

Should work now.
If you open the settings for this avd in the avd manager, you will have to set this setting in `config.ini` again.

Answer (score 0):

In your Android emulator's avd files folder (normally it is named as same as the name of the emulator plus ".avd" at the end, and it should be "Nexus_5_API_23_x86.avd" in your case) inside "`~/.android/avd`" directory.

Find the file named "hardware-qemu.ini", and make sure there is a line set to "`hw.sdCard = true`".